# How do I use the DateTimeFormatter correctly to pass it onto a Repository to execute a query?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, datetime-format

I have been trying to use the DateTimeFormatter API to convert a String into a Date format and query it in the repository interface. However, I keep on getting errors in my SearchController and cannot figure out why.

SearchController:

```
    @GetMapping("/search")
public String searchAccessInfoByDate(@RequestParam("startDate") String startDate, @RequestParam("endDate") String endDate, Model model) {
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-mm-dd");
    LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDate.parse(startDate, dateTimeFormatter1).atTime(LocalTime.MIN);
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-mm-dd");
    LocalDateTime date2 = LocalDate.parse(endDate, dateTimeFormatter2).atTime(LocalTime.MAX);
    List<AccessInfo> foundAccessInfos = accessInfoRepository.searchAccessInfoByDate(date1, date2);
    model.addAttribute("foundAccessInfos", foundAccessInfos);
    return "search";
}
```

AccessInfoRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface AccessInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<AccessInfo, Long> {
    @Query("select i from AccessInfo i where i.accessDate between ?1 and ?2")
    List<AccessInfo> searchAccessInfoByDate(LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate);
}
```

AccessInfo.java(Entity):

```
package com.assignment.restapi.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class AccessInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String accessedApi;
    private Integer httpResponseStatusCode;
    private Integer accessCount;
    private Integer averageRequestTime;
    private LocalDateTime accessDate;

    public AccessInfo() {

    }

    public AccessInfo(String accessedApi, Integer httpResponseStatusCode, Integer accessCount,  Integer averageRequestTime, LocalDateTime accessDate) {
        this.accessedApi = accessedApi;
        this.httpResponseStatusCode = httpResponseStatusCode;
        this.accessCount = accessCount;
        this.averageRequestTime = averageRequestTime;
        this.accessDate = accessDate;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAccessedApi() {
        return accessedApi;
    }

    public void setAccessedApi(String accessedApi) {
        this.accessedApi = accessedApi;
    }

    public Integer getHttpResponseStatusCode() {
        return httpResponseStatusCode;
    }

    public void setHttpResponseStatusCode(Integer httpResponseStatusCode) {
        this.httpResponseStatusCode = httpResponseStatusCode;
    }

    public Integer getAccessCount() {
        return accessCount;
    }

    public void setAccessCount(Integer accessCount) {
        this.accessCount = accessCount;
    }

    public Integer getAverageRequestTime() {
        return averageRequestTime;
    }

    public void setAverageRequestTime(Integer averageRequestTime) {
        this.averageRequestTime = averageRequestTime;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getAccessDate() {
        return accessDate;
    }

    public void setAccessDate(LocalDateTime accessDate) {
        this.accessDate = accessDate;
    }
}
```

search.html(Where the search result gets displayed):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="/search" style="padding: 10px 0">
    <div>
        <input type="date" name="startDate" th:value="startDate">
        〜
        <input type="date" name="endDate" th:value="endDate">
        <input type="submit" value="検索">
    </div>
</form>
<table border="1" th:if="${foundAccessInfos}">
    <tr>
        <th>APIエンドポイント</th>
        <th>ステータスコード</th>
        <th>アクセス回数[ns]</th>
        <th>リクエスト平均時間</th>
        <th>アクセスされた日付け</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Current error:

"Text '2018-09-30' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {Year=2018, MinuteOfHour=9, DayOfMonth=30},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed"]}

Comment: What error do you get? Can you provide it?

Comment: What is the string date that you're passing?

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya "Text '2018-09-29' could not be parsed at index 4"

Comment: @MadhuBhat <input type="date" name="startDate" th:value="startDate">

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya the right pattern is `yyyy-MM-dd` and not `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: For parsing a date in yyyy-mm-dd format you don’t need a formatter at all since this format is the (ISO 8601) standard. I suggest `LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDate.parse(startDate).atStartOfDay();` (similarly for end date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your `DateTimeFormatter` pattern which is not able to parse the date that you are providing. You need to use the `DateTimeFormatter` pattern as below

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Please refer the `DateTimeFormatter` [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for detailed info regarding the patterns.

Comment: hmmm I got the error away but now the query returns nothing. I edited my code in the question, could you take a look?

Comment: @Blaze so you aren't getting the parsing error anymore right? And what do you mean by the query returns nothing? Is the query being formed correctly? You would need to provide more details to find out where the problem is.

Comment: For parsing a date in yyyy-mm-dd format you don’t need a formatter at all since this format is the (ISO 8601) standard. I suggest `LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDate.parse(startDate).atStartOfDay();` (similarly for end date).

Answer (score 1):

If you used the answer from @Madhu Bhat, change in your repository class the ? to : and 1 to startDate and 2 to endDate, I don't know if you can use ?1 and ?2 in jpa but I have my repositories like the below code.

```
@Repository
public interface AccessInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<AccessInfo, Long> {
    @Query("select i from AccessInfo i where i.accessDate between :startDate and :endDate")
    List<AccessInfo> searchAccessInfoByDate(LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate);
}
```

Hope this helps.